# Separator with asterisks and lines

Tags: separator

I want to have a separator consisting of three asterisks and line.

Have the following, but it is quite messed up.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\UndeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{TS1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textasteriskcentered}{OT1}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{OT1}{\raisebox{-.7ex}[1ex][0pt]{*}}

\newcommand{\separ}[1][1]
 {
  \par\vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \noindent
  \hbox to \dimexpr 0.5\linewidth - #1\linewidth / 2\relax{}
  \xrfill[0.5ex]{0.4pt}
  \;\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\;
  \xrfill[0.5ex]{0.4pt}
  \hbox to \dimexpr 0.5\linewidth - #1\linewidth / 2\relax{}
  \vskip0.5\baselineskip\par
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Some text

\separ[0.2]

More Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please, ensure that the code can be run; in this case you forgot `\usepackage{xhfill}`.

Comment: @Celest: Remember, this is not a forum. Be specific in your questioning; stating that "[something is] messed up" doesn't mean anything in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the macro `\separ` needn't take an argument, its definition can be simplified considerably.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\let\tac\textasteriskcentered % two handy shortcut macros
\let\ted\textemdash
\newcommand\separ{%
   \begin{center}
     \ted\ted\ \tac\,\tac\,\tac\ \ted\ted%
   \end{center}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1][1-3] % filler text
\separ
\lipsum[2][1-3] % more filler text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is quite messed up.

Maybe, you want to define the following macro:

```
\def\separ[#1]{%
   \par\medskip
   \centerline{\crule{#1\hsize/3} \lower.7ex\hbox{*\,*\,*} \crule{#1\hsize/3}}
   \medskip
}
\def\crule#1{\vrule height.6ex depth-\dimexpr.6ex-.4pt width\dimexpr#1\relax\relax}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not your asterisks that are too high, but the rule drawn by `xhfill` that's too low.

You can get the right centering with some low level programming so you can make reference to the “axis height” that's what the asterisk is centered with respect to. No guessing of dimensions.

Using a `\vrule` of the desired size is better than the indirect filling.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\separ}[1][1]{%
  \par\nopagebreak\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
  \hbox to \linewidth{%
    \check@mathfonts
    \hss
    \vrule width \dimeval{#1\linewidth/2}
           height \dimeval{\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt}
           depth -\dimeval{\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt}%
    \;\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\;%
    \vrule width \dimeval{#1\linewidth/2}
           height \dimeval{\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt}
           depth -\dimeval{\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt}%
    \hss
  }
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text

\separ[0.2]

More Text

\end{document}
```

[image]